# Xcode , iphone versions

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new on iphone I want just change something little to a project. I have A mac os  10.6 , xcode3.2.6 and an iphone 4.3.5 I import the project and it runs ok. When i try to add the app on device I have 2 problems :
1. Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version
2. No code signature found

I can run the app on iphone if I don t update xcode?
If I update xcode can I import my project even if it was done in a previous version?

Thank you ,

Raluca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run the app on a device the code must be signed with a valid developer certificate.

Yes, if you update XCode you can still open projects that were created with previous versions of XCode.

Comment: so if i singn the application is no need to update to xcode 4 ?